# Virtual IEnumerable<T> that compiles empty

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, virtual, ienumerable, yield-return

I am making a base class that has a `virtual` method called "GetBaseAddresses()". It has as a return type `IEnumerable<Uri>`. The base class will not `yield` any results if enumerated, but a derived class has the option to override the method and return as many items as it wants.

Here is the base method:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Uri> GetBaseAddresses() { }
```

The problem is, that won't compile. You *must* return a value for the compiler to be happy. So, because I want to have an empty result, I would just return `null`, right?

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Uri> GetBaseAddresses() { return null; }
```

The problem there is that if someone does a `foreach` on an instance of the base class, they will crash with a runtime error of "Object reference not set..."

So, recalling that the `yield return` keyword does some magic with the C# compiler... I came up with this compiler hack (that works by the way).

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Uri> GetBaseAddresses()
{
    if (false) { yield return new Uri(""); }
}
```

Strangely enough, even though the "if (false) { ... }" code gets completely compiled away - the compiler is happy with me meeting the "must return a value" requirement, and does exactly what I want - that is, an empty result set that is safe to enumerate.

**My question is - Is there a way to do this without my compiler trick?**

Comment: Why not use an abstract base class and method?

Comment: Because the majority of the class has functionality... there are simply a couple of methods that are `virtual`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just return an empty enumerable in the base method.

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<Uri> GetBaseAddresses()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<Uri>();
    }
```

Or if you're targeting a version of the .NET framework < 3.5 return an empty List.

Comment: All 3 answers were great - yours was first (and exposes a class in the .Net framework that was explicitly designed for this situation)... nice :)

Answer (score 10):

Use an empty array, or:

```
yield break; //end enumeration
```

Pulling up svick's idea from the comments:

```
return Enumerable.Empty<Uri>();
```

This is faster because `Enumerable.Empty` always returns a cached, pre-allocated instance of some empty enumerable.

Comment: Your thinking was right though: You need to use enumerator features to make the compiler treat this method as an enumerator.

Comment: `Enumerable.Empty()` is better than an empty array, because the array would be created every time, while `Empty` is cached.

Answer (score 5):

Built in arrays support IEnumerable so you can use:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Uri> GetBaseAddresses() 
{     
      return new Uri[0];
}
```

Comment: @TimothyKhouri Addendum: to use "yeld _something_" (break or return) will always force the compiler to create a IEnumerable class to return to callers. If it's empty (because optimized away by the compiler or without values by _design_ as with yield break without any yeld return) then the compiler will simply create an **empty** enumerable class (take a look to generated code with Reflector or ILDasm). +1 'cause an empty array is much much more lightweight than that.

Comment: I did know of (and think of) this option - but I was hoping to avoid creating a new object each time. It seems that there is no way around that, so I'm going to make a private static readonly _empty variable and return that every time.

Comment: @TimothyKhouri: having static empty array member is a common solution - empty arrays are essentially immutable

Answer (score 0):

The reason why empty method doesn't work is that the compiler assumes that if you don't use the `yield` keyword in the method, then you want to create a normal method, not an iterator. That's also why your `if (false)` hack works.

To properly write a method that returns an empty collection, you could either return an empty collection in the usual way:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Uri> GetBaseAddresses()
{
    return Enumerable.Empty<Uri>();
}
```

Or you could use `yield break`:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Uri> GetBaseAddresses()
{
    yield break;
}
```